# How to call javascript after every ajax or full request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have some JavaScript code that binds a click event to certain elements click events as seen below.

```
    $(".alert-message .close").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        $(this).slideUp(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is called in the document ready event so normally it works fine until i fire an ajax request that updates parts of the page. This newly created part doesn't have the click event added and i end up having to recall this code for every ajax request, resulting in a lot of duplication.

I am looking for a way to write this JavaScript code once and it to be called in any scenario. Is there some event handler that will be called after any ajax or normal request?

Bootstrap dismissable alert message work after any ajax request so there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which version of jQuery you're using you should use either `delegate` or `on` instead of directly binding click. Try something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.alert-message .close', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        $(this).slideUp(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation and bind the event to a parent of `.alert-message .close` that doesn't get recreated:

```
$(document).on('click', ".alert-message .close", function(e) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(parentDivOrContainer).on('click', ".alert-message .close", function(){...});
```

`parentDivOrContainer` can be any container element that is not affected by ajax call.